# YouTube Copyright

Tags: copyright, youtube

What could happen if I copy some content from an article on a website and narrate it on my YouTube channel with some modifications? What copyright issues would I be facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have created a "[derivative work](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ14.pdf)" (PDF link) of the original. If you did so without permission then you will have violated the copyright of the creator.

The link above is for the US, but most jurisdictions are substantially similar.